# aws-sdk-go-v2 attributevalue.Marshaler interface not working

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb

I try to implement the aws-sdk-go-v2 attributevalue.Marshaler interface but it has no effect. An empty object is always stored on the db.

I have the following struct

```
type ID struct {
    value string
}
```

it tried both versions of the marshaler

```
func (id *ID) MarshalDynamoDBAttributeValue() (types.AttributeValue, error) {
    return &types.AttributeValueMemberM{
        Value: map[string]types.AttributeValue{
            "value": &types.AttributeValueMemberS{Value: id.value},
        },
    }, nil
}
```

and

```
func (id *ID) MarshalDynamoDBAttributeValue() (types.AttributeValue, error) {
    return &types.AttributeValueMemberS{Value: id.value}, nil
}
```

in both cases I can see with the debugger that it enters on the function and looks likes the returned value is correct. But after that when I check on the db the id is stored as an object without properties.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the link on the ID

that will not work:

```
func (id *ID) MarshalDynamoDBAttributeValue() (types.AttributeValue, error) {
    return &types.AttributeValueMemberS{Value: id.value}, nil
}
```

but the same thing without link works

```golang
func (id ID) MarshalDynamoDBAttributeValue() (types.AttributeValue, error) {
    return &types.AttributeValueMemberS{Value: id.value}, nil
}
```